# How to can i stop bxslider from sliding if there is only one image on the slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a website with multiple pages, some of the pages are using bxslider to display the slides. Anyway there are few page which only have one slide. But even with only one slide, the slider still keep auto sliding.

Since this looks quite weird, i decided to disable the auto sliding by adding 
`<ul class="bxslider" style="transform: none !important;>`.

But somehow the "transform: none" does not render on the website.

Then, i tried adding the js

```
$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
auto: ($('.bxslider').children().length < 2) ? false : true
});
```

And this does not work too. So anybody can advice me on this please.

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24654670/bx-slider-how-to-disable-slide-show-when-only-one-image-is-present

Comment: Thanks, let me try..